# Could not initialize Direct3D VS 2015 (Win 10)

Tags: c++, directx, windows-10, directx-11

I'm following the DirectX 11 Series 2 tutorial on [rastertek.com](http://rastertek.com/). Presently I'm on Tutorial 3 (Initializing DirectX) and for some reason the CreateDeviceAndSwapChain function keeps failing when I run the program. I have followed the steps to link the Windows 10 SDK libraries and includes to the project from here ([rastertek.com/dx12tut01.html](http://rastertek.com/dx12tut01.html)) and my GPU is an Nvidia 780 Ti. I've also tried his pre-compiled .exe and that works fine. What's the problem? Let me know if screenshots are needed!

```
//enable debug mode
UINT flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

#if defined( DEBUG ) || defined( _DEBUG )
flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif 

//create the swap chain, d3d device, and d3d device context
result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, flags, &featureLevel, 1, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain, &m_device, NULL, &m_deviceContext);
if (FAILED(result)) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Does it succeed if you remove the D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag? If so, it just means you don't have the SDK Layers aka "Graphics Tools" installed from Windows 10's "Optional Features".

Comment: As Adam notes, you are likely just missing the debug device support for your version of Windows. See [Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition.aspx) and [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/31/visual-studio-2015-and-graphics-tools-for-windows-10.aspx).

Comment: I had similar issue, i just enabled the "Graphics Tools" in Win10 Optional features, like @AdamMiles mentioned, that is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case, i have a laptop with intel hd 4400 and geforce 840m (using win10 + visual studio 2015), and i had set featureLevel to 11.1 manually, turned out that intel supports that feature level, but geforce suports maximum 11.0. Anyway, its still not clear what is your problem, what error message is, or anything else, so you can try lower feature level, pass 0 as flags.